# Error: UITableViewController loaded the "TableViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView HOWEVER I've already deleted the NIB file

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

In my app I was in the process of changing a UITableView from being added programmatically to being added by a XIB. Decided to scratch the idea and go back but now the app is crashing with

> message:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "TableViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'

I was reading elsewhere on SO that I should go back and delete connections from the NIB but I already deleted the NIB file! So any suggestions please?

```
//ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat rowHeight;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arr;

@end

//ViewController.m
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "AddNewExViewController.h"
#import "Exercises.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize context, arr;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
    {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Exercises";

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercises"
inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setFetchBatchSize:20];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *newArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
    [request setSortDescriptors:newArray];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *results = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    [self setArr:results];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash target:self action:@selector(deleteAll)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(add)];

    self.tableView.rowHeight = 60.f;
}
```

**Edit:**

```
//AppDelegate.m
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    TableViewController *table = [[TableViewController alloc] init];

    table.context = self.managedObjectContext;

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:table];

    /*nav.toolbarHidden = NO;*/ //uncomment if you want a tool bar at bottom of tableView

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the ViewController object

Comment: @Paulw11 I've added the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method from the AppDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you init this controller ? Is it the only controller in the program ? If so please post some code on Appdelegate didfinishloadingwithoptions

*Edit

do a clean up of your project (xcode > project menu > clean) and reset your simulator & see if problem persists. also make sure your code reaches initWithStyle method in TableViewController by putting a breakpoint there.

Comment: Solved: even though I had reset the simulator, restarted Xcode and even restarted the Mac, I had forgot to delete the app from the simulator. Once I did that it worked. Xcode was still accessing my my NIB even though it was removed from the project and the simulator had it cached. Thank you for your help.